# Is it redundant in Swift to use weak and optional for the same variable?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in Swift and in the [Apple docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) I see:

> Use a weak reference whenever it is valid for that reference to become >nil at some point during its lifetime.

**Shouldn't I achieve that just by using "?" for optional types?**

in other words:

**Do the `weak` and `?` overlap?**

The compiler complains if I don't define a variable as `optional` when is `weak`, so I feel like I could just remove it and forget about it, but I feel I'm just misunderstanding it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, weak and optional are not the same, but there is some interplay between the two.

Optional just means that a variable can be `nil`, either by assigning nil yourself, or becoming nil through some other means.

The `weak` keyword has to do with memory management. When a variable is **not** `weak` (i.e. it is strong), it means that ARC holds a strong reference to the instance that is assigned. So even when there are no other references to it, the instance will stay alive in memory because the variable still "holds it".

When a a variable is `weak`, it does not hold a strong reference to it. That means that when there are no other strong references to it, the instance will be deallocated, and the variable will become `nil` automatically. This also explains why a weak variable **must** be optional.

The document that you linked to actually explains this quite clearly.

Comment: **This also explains why a weak variable must be optional.** no ,must is not mandatory here it would be

Comment: @Sh_Khan: I don't understand what you mean exactly. Do you mean it can also be an implicitly unwrapped *optional*?

Answer (score 2):

**`weak`** is related to memory management that ARC should remove that variable from memory or not. If your variable is weak then ARC would clear that memory to which it is pointing to as soon as all the strong references to that memory destroyed and when the memory is cleared then even the varaible is non-optional it will have nill because its memory is cleared.

But the **`optional`** has nothing to do with memory and it is directly related to the variable value that it can either contains the actual value or the nil.

Answer (score 1):

Optional and non-optional properties differ in that optionals may be `nil`, while non-optional cannot.

`weak` and `strong` (property is `strong` by default without `weak` keyword) properties differ in that `weak` don't increase property's retain count, while `strong` do. If a `weak` property isn't strongly retained somewhere else, it will be deallocated. `weak` properties must also be optional.